# How to Save Captured image File to data/data/<package.name>/cache ?

Tags: android, caching, android-camera, android-file, android-camera-intent

I need to secure the images which i am taking. from android [Android Training](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)
    i am able to take full sized image. but this is not my need.
i need to save full sized image to cache dir (/data/data//cache) and i wil delete these cache folder when user leaves my application.

this is  my code, which  the file is successfully created in cache directory. but the file size is zero, no image written

```
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File file=null;
        try {
            String fileName = "506214";
            file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, this.getCacheDir());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error while creating file
        }
        photoURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Toast.makeText(this, photoURI.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        camera_image.setImageURI(photoURI);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this my friend

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
```

and dont forget to dd permisoon in manifiest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: sorry bro.. not creating files in data/data/myapp/cache

Answer (score 0):

If you are in `Activity` class use `this.getCacheDir()` as first argument for `File` and second arg for your file name to store in cache dir.

```
   File f = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "capture_"+ imageNumber++);
   try {
      f.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Below is how I captured and save in cache until I upload to S3 (this code is inside `onActivityResult()`):

```
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        //create a file to write bitmap data
        File f = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "capture_"+ imageNumber++);
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        Bitmap bitmap = photo;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is only saving the small thumbnail of the image, not the full size image